# When filter in micronaut and subscribe the result get Only one subscriber allowed Error

Tags: micronaut

The micronaut filter process will return Publisher
but if I try to subscribe the result from the publisher
It throws

```
13:37:24.721 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Only one subscriber allowed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one subscriber allowed
    at io.micronaut.core.async.processor.SingleSubscriberProcessor.subscribe(SingleSubscriberProcessor.java:55)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.binders.PublisherBodyBinder.lambda$null$0(PublisherBodyBinder.java:83)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromPublisher.subscribeActual(SingleFromPublisher.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
```

BAD controller

```
    @Post
    public Single<Map<String, String>> test(@Body Single<Map<String, String>> input) {
        return input;
    }
```

Good Controller

```
    @Post
    public Single<Map<String, String>> test(@Body Map<String, String> input) {
        return Single.just(input);
    }
```

Simple filter

```
    @Override
    public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {
        Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>>  actual = chain.proceed(request);
    Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>>  actual = chain.proceed(request);
    actual.subscribe(mysubscribe);
    return actual;
    }
```

I feel it's a bug. just ask here first.
Thanks

Comment: I try to work around on my filter. 
not subscribe two times.